# Data warehouse and type 2 SCD and/or daily snapshot fact tables

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, datamart

I am having a trouble deciding which is better for my scenario. the involved dimensions on this scenario are

1. Employee Dimension

   ```
   ╔═════════════╦════════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
   ║ EmployeeKey ║ EmployeeID ║ DeptID ║ Salary ║ StartDate ║ EndDate  ║ Active ║
   ╠═════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
   ║ 1           ║ 1          ║ 1      ║ 9000   ║ 20150901  ║ 20150930 ║ FALSE  ║
   ║ 2           ║ 2          ║ 3      ║ 5000   ║ 20150901  ║ NULL     ║ TRUE   ║
   ║ 3           ║ 1          ║ 1      ║ 9500   ║ 20150930  ║ NULL     ║ TRUE   ║
   ╚═════════════╩════════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
   ```
2. Department Dimension

   ```
   ╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════╦════════╗
   ║ DepartmentKey ║ DepartmentID ║ Name ║ Sepc ║ StartDate ║ EndDate ║ Active ║
   ╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬════════╣
   ║ 1             ║ 1            ║ XXXX ║ AWK  ║ 20150901  ║ NULL    ║ TRUE   ║
   ║ 2             ║ 2            ║ YYYY ║ AUTO ║ 20150901  ║ NULL    ║ TRUE   ║
   ║ 3             ║ 3            ║ ZZZZ ║ AMD  ║ 20150901  ║ NULL    ║ TRUE   ║
   ╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════╩════════╝
   ```
3. Employee Fact table(Per day)
4. Department Fact Table(Per day)

My questions

1. what is the proper and most sufficient way to implement the daily snapshot fact tables knowing that Department Dimension contains active 7 million records and Departments Dimension contains active 500,000 record.
2. is it sufficient to populate fact employee and fact department daily and repeat the records on daily basis?

I am using SQL Server 2014 database and expected to use OLAP

Comment: What are the facts that you are storing, and their measurable attributes?

Comment: Thanks David, the needed measures are the count of employees and count of departments at any given time

Comment: So your fact table might actually be "factless", in that it could just store: date, employee_id, department_id? Are there any classifications of the employee or the department or the employment in general (days employed so far, job_id?) etc that you'd like to be able to measure or filter by?

Comment: exactly, it's just the employee attributes and department attributes over time. so should i use the factless fact table approach ?

like this
EmployeeKey,DepartmentKey,DateKey

knowing that the window required by the client is 5 years 

is it correct to have 7 million record repeated every day for 5 years in the factless table?

Comment: I think it depends on what you need to actually report. If it was just a count of the number of employees per department by date, then you could just have DepartmentKey, DateKey, employee_count. If you needed to track the departments of a bunch of employees over time (show me the current departments of all employees who were in customer services on 1st Jan) then you need to track employee id in the fact table.

Comment: If you need to count the distinct number of employees in a data range of one month, then you might also need to track employee id in the fact table, except that your fact table could be (department, date, employee count, arriving employee count, leaving employees count). Otherwise it's 12.7 billion facts that you have to store.

Comment: Yes, David, thanks very much for your help,  I need to have count of Employees, count of departments per day, drill down from department to employees in it. but do you think having average of 7M record for the given time window will be efficient with the SQL Server DBMS?  it's like 7M * 365 * 5 = Average of 12775000000 record on single fact table

Comment: I think you're going to have EmployeeKey, DepartmentKey, DateKey then. Maybe an indicator for "new employee", as that's computationally challenging for bulk data but can be computed once when the new day is loaded.

Comment: Thanks very much David for your support. i think i will have to go with the 12.7B record to store + partitioning, customer is very strict on getting the employee record at any given time and they want it to be available on the reporting tool to slide and dice over it.  also the customer is a strategic center and these data are often used to analyze employee behavior over time. even grouping the employee and department for all their attribute will only save ~2M records .. for the new arrived employee, i think it will be a very nice added value for the reporting side.

Comment: You can consider other flags as well ... if the employee just moved dept then maybe have a "came from dept" id in there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to snapshot your fact on daily basis? Fact is supposed to have all the data. Date keys in the fact should be enough to deal with date based queries.

Also, I do not recommend making employees and dimensions as facts- they look straight forward dimensions. A fact should be measuring something which I do not see here. Build your fact around some processes/ transactions done by employees who work in some department. Link this fact to the two dimensions and the date dimension. If you want to retain history of the changes in the transactions, make your dimension SCD enabled.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, they want a daily snapshot because they want a daily count of employees and they want to be able to drill down and drill across over employee attribute on a daily basis. same for department.  

i am already using the employee and department as a dimension for the transaction and business processes fact table.

the problem is that they need a daily count of the departments and employees

and the ability to drill down from department to employee in any given date

Comment: Read up on building dimension hierarchies, it will give you idea on how to allow drilling down.
For counts, just fire a query on the fact table with proper date bound ranges and you can get counts for any day/ month

Answer (score 0):

Possible layout is to have a SCD2 table for each dimension.

Here is an example for DEPARTMENT
[image]

Note that I added a numeric *VERSION* attribute to uniquely define the order of the versions.
The column *VALIDFROM_DATE* corresponds to the validity of your snapshot used to build the dimension.
Typically also VALIDTO Date is added to optimize access - with some dummy high values for open (last) versions.

Note also that the design districts between validfrom_date and start_date.
The former is the timestamp you get the information (from the snapshot), the latter is the *logical* validity.
In the example you got on 20.08.2013 the information that on 01.09.2013 a new department will be created.
The second version represents a rename of a department, the third show that on 1.9.2015 this department was closed.

Such a dimension is typically maintained with an ETL job processing periodically the snapshots, recognizing the changes and building the dimension.

From the fact tables (i.e. tables with transactions referencing Department) the dimension is referenced with DEPARTMENTKEY and optionally validity date (to match the proper version).

You may also set up a **current view** of the dimension (with PK DEPARTMENTKEY). This is trivial and can be done with view or materialized view with query
such as follows:

```
 with dept as (
 select 
   DEPARTMENTKEY,  
   min(VALIDFROM_DATE) over (partition by DEPARTMENTKEY) created_date,
   VALIDFROM_DATE last_change_date, DEPARTMENTID, NAME,
   FIRST_VALUE(NAME) over (partition by DEPARTMENTKEY order by VERSION) as INITIAL_NAME,
   SEPC, START_DATE, END_DATE, IS_ACTIVE,
   row_number() over (partition by DEPARTMENTKEY order by VERSION desc) as rn
 from Department_history)
 select 
   DEPARTMENTKEY, CREATED_DATE, LAST_CHANGE_DATE, DEPARTMENTID, NAME, INITIAL_NAME, SEPC, START_DATE, END_DATE, IS_ACTIVE
 from dept
 where rn = 1
 order by DepartmentKey
```

You may profit from all date of the history table - see the attributes CREATED_DATE and INITIAL_NAME (you may implement elegantly SCD3 (new columns) at very low cost).

[image]

**Update VALID TO Date**

As mentioned above for practical reasons the history dimension offen implements VALIDTO date. This column is maintained in the ETL job and one possible solution for daily snapshots is to set it to

- dummy lagre day for open versions
- day preceeding the VALIDTO day of the next version

Note that there are other options, but the big advantage of this schema is that you can always query the proper version with this predicate

```
 where to_date('01012015','ddmmyyyy') between validfrom_date and validto_date
```

I add here the VALIDTO date with the following query

```
 create table department_history2 as 
 with dept as (
 select  
 DEPARTMENTKEY, VERSION, VALIDFROM_DATE, 
 lead(VALIDFROM_DATE-1,1,to_date('31122500','ddmmyyyy')) over (partition by DEPARTMENTKEY order by VERSION) as VALIDTO_DATE,
 DEPARTMENTID, NAME, SEPC, START_DATE, END_DATE, IS_ACTIVE
 from Department_history
 )
 select * from dept
```

**Update Query the Count per Day**

To reconstruct the daily count from your history dimension you must first 
create the relevant part of the time dimension (one record per day) and than join it to the history dimension. Finaly perform the aggregation.

Here an example to "decompress" 4 days from 30.8.2015

```
 with snapshots as (
 select to_date('30082015','ddmmyyyy') -1 + rownum transaction_date from dual connect by level <= 4),
 deps_snaps as (
 select 
  transaction_date, DEPARTMENTKEY, VERSION, VALIDFROM_DATE, VALIDTO_DATE,      DEPARTMENTID, NAME, SEPC, START_DATE, END_DATE, IS_ACTIVE
 from   department_history2, snapshots
 where transaction_date between  validfrom_date and validto_date
 )
 -- aggregate
 select transaction_date, count(*) active_dept_count
 from deps_snaps
 where is_active = 'Y'
 group by transaction_date
 order by transaction_date;

 transaction_date     active_dept_count
 30.08.2015 00:00:00    2
 31.08.2015 00:00:00    2
 01.09.2015 00:00:00    1
 02.09.2015 00:00:00    1
```

The big advantage of this approach is that if a department is changed say once in 3 years (typical interval in big companies) the dimension will not have 5 * 365 times more records but only approximately twice as much in 5 years.

Comment: Hi Marmite,

Thanks very much for your contribute.

they want to have the count of employees or departments to be listed over day.

i already implements both as SCD 2 tables.

but how can i utilized the output of the materialized view you've created to get the output of having a very query efficent structure for having the count of departments on each day in the year.

THanks a lot